# How should I design a code-block editor in the style of Lego Mindstorms?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have started a project where I need to design an application that will work as a code-block editor, much like Lego Mindstorms and [Blockly, a google project](https://developers.google.com/blockly/).

**What are the possible approaches for designing such an application in Java?**

More specifically, assuming I have one block A, how can I define which other blocks can be connected with it? What I think of is using subclasses and checking the hierarchy, or another possible solution could be some kind of 2D table that will verify a connection is valid(although I think it might get too big?).

p.s: I hope this is within the scope of SO questions. If not please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what you're looking to accomplish? Generally-speaking, "I'm undertaking a huge project, how should I do it?" questions are too broad for SO, but I'm not familiar with Mindstorms' editor so I may be overestimating your scope here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lego Mindstorms is basically a stripped-down modified version of National Instruments' LabVIEW programming language.

I think the project you are trying to accomplish will be quite involved. This will not be an easy task to do right unless you only have a very limited number of actions that the code which you can build with your editor will be able to perform.

Essentially, you are trying to develop an entirely new programming language here. And before even thinking about the details of implementing the GUI, you need to pin down the "grammar" and other semantics of the language you are designing. For example, are you going to support for loops? while loops? case/switch statements? if statements? gotos? throwing and catching exceptions?

I'm not sure what your requirements and resources are, but you might be better off trying to call National Instruments to see if they will build something like the MindStorms IDE for/with you or seeing if there are other open source languages out there that you can modify to fit your needs.

There is an open LabVIEW clone, but it's a German page: http://www.myopenlab.de/.

Here are a couple of others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language.

Comment: This is a group project and I am assigned to work on the design. We have the language and its complete ebnf definition, and what we need to do is create a visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not beholden to graphical approaches, and as I am unsure how Lego MindStorms works, it is possible that [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) may qualify as a solution.

*"ANTLR is a powerful parser generator for reading, processing, executing, or translating structured text or binary files. It's widely used to build languages, tools, and frameworks. From a grammar, ANTLR generates a parser that can build and walk parse trees."*

Comment: This may prove useful at some part of the application although GUI is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar thing my C# project. I used a [tree view control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/Generic_Tree_View/GenericTreeView.JPG), and I allowed the user to add actions which would show up in the tree view, and the program would run through the tree view nodes, calling their actions. Behind the scenes, I used [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769721/allow-the-user-to-arrange-methods/12769812#12769812). Comment if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/)? That is what it is intended for, after all. It is available under the [Apache License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License) on [gitub](https://github.com/google/blockly). If you don't want to use Blockly, please let us know how Blockly doesn't fit your needs. :-)